# Prefabs and materials not working on another system

Tags: unity

Our problem seems like rare, as I did research and none find to answer my question.

The problem is, I have created prefabs ,materials on my system and then exported it to my partner's System.

Now when my partner import it on his system all prefabs and materials I created showing "white" icon (not gray)

When we try to drag it to scene its not working.

Does anyone know answer to it?

Comment: Can you describe the method you used to export these files, with exact details (including the file names)? Also, are you seeing any errors in the console or the inspector? This can occur if the metadata files are missing or mismatched, but transferring files as a Unity package usually avoids this problem.

Comment: hi,I used unity's export method to transfer file....yes I do think so it will be meta files problem, yet if I create new project in my system n import that package, its working fine, but in my partner's system its not working...till now it used to work this way in his n my system with no problem...

Comment: Sounds like your partner may already have copies of some of those files, with different metadata IDs. So the cross-file references, which are all done by ID, don't match. You can verify whether this is the issue by setting Edit->Project Settings->Editor->Asset Serialization Mode to "Force Text" and then examining the metafiles for some of the problematic assets or the assets they reference. You should see some differences/errors in the inspectors at least if these links are mismatched though...

Comment: the problem still exists even when we import into new project....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Teamwork in Unity](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/35/teamwork-in-unity)